# Database Transaction Between Two Controller and Two Page

Tags: php, database, forms, postgresql, codeigniter

I will try to explain my question and problem, if you need other information kindly comment it below.

I have a page name **form.php** :

This form function is submit value

and then value from **form.php** capture by a controller called **formController.php**, inside the controller look like :

```
$this->db->trans_start();
```

-- query INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES('1', 'a'); <- i can sure it working after use $this->db->query($sql);

```
$this->load->view('nextForm');
```

With the controller above then we go to nextForm without commit it. After i submit nextForm.php inside the controller (another controller) called nextFormController :

```
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

> **Summary :**
>
> I try start a database transaction in one page and one
>   controller, and i try to complete the transaction in another page and
>   controller (different controller). But I get that the result of the query
>   inside formController.php is not inserted into database.
>
> Anyone can help me to explain and fix my code without move
>   trans_complete to formController.php? cause i need to complete the
>   query after the second page submit correctly.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not so firm with Codeignter, however I would strongly assume that you can't start a database transaction in the one request and complete it in another request. Collect the data to complete the transaction within a session object and if you have all data at hand to perform the database interaction, start doing so. Or alterantively move on to the second controller w/o doing a new request. But I don't know if Codeigniter supports that either.

Comment: As @hakre has said you cannot start transactions and end them on a different page. A transaction relates to a connection and a fresh one is used on each page load. Note also that controllers are not the place to be running transactions but these should be used within models.

Comment: How if i pass the $this to other controller? but if it possible , how to pass $this of $this->db->transaction_start() to View and then to Controller back?